# Is there any way of viewing SakuraDB database files on Android?

Tags: android, database, root

I'm trying to find a way of viewing and possibly editing a sakuradb database file on Android, however, I'm unable to find anything that is able to open the files :(

Has anyone had any luck with this in the past? or does anyone have any idea on how I would go about this challenge??

I have a rooted android device, and I am running CentOS 6.6 as my OS with wine installed and up to date.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I have already tried SQLite Manager on Firefox (Maybe should have mentioned earlier).

This is the error I get from SQLite Manager - 
```SQLiteManager: Error in opening file sakura.db - either the file is encrypted or corrupt
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x8052000b (NS_ERROR_FILE_CORRUPTED) [mozIStorageService.openUnsharedDatabase]```

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, the Sakura.db files are encrypted database files, and without the corresponding key, or a way to find the key, there is no way of actually reading the file, even with software like SQLCipher and the likes.